# When swiping to the left, the list item is not deleted

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I'm new to flutter. I have a task where there is an item to delete the created note to the left. When deleting a list item with a swipe, it is deleted until I do a Hot restart. When I do a Hot restart the item reappears.Maybe I have a bug in the code. Help me please.

```
import 'dart:convert';
        import 'dart:collection';
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
        import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
        import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
        
        
        class Home extends StatefulWidget {
         const Home ({key}): super(key: key);
        
          @override
          State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
        }
          class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
        
          final myController = TextEditingController();
          bool submit = false;
        
          Color mainColor = Color(0xFFEEEFF5);
          Color secColor = Color(0xFF3A3A3A);
          Color tdBlue = Color(0xFF5F52EE);
        
        
        String temp = "";
          List<String> todoList = [];
        String index = "";
        
          @override
          void initState() {
        
            super.initState();
        
            myController.addListener(() {
              setState(() {
                submit = myController.text.isNotEmpty;
              });
            });
        
            omLoadData();
          }
        
          submitData() async {
            setState(() {
              todoList.add(temp);
              clearText();
            });
            SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            await prefs.setStringList('todo_list', todoList);
          }
        
          omLoadData() async {
            SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            final data = prefs.getStringList("todo_list");
            todoList.addAll(data!);
          }
        
          @override
          void dispose() {
            // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
            myController.dispose();
            super.dispose();
          }
        
          void clearText() {
              myController.clear();
          }
        
        
             @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context){
           return Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: mainColor,
             appBar: AppBar(
               elevation: 0.0,
               backgroundColor: secColor,
              title: Text ('ToDo - List', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26.5, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),),
             ),
                body: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
        
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 15.0,
                        left: 13.0,
                        right: 8.0,
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextField(
                              onChanged: (String value) {
                                temp = value;
                              },
        
                              controller: myController,
                              decoration:
                              InputDecoration(
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.notes, color: Colors.orangeAccent,),
                                  labelText: 'Замітка',
                                  hintText: 'Введіть замітку',
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0),),
        
                                  ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 10.0,
                          ),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: tdBlue),
        
                            onPressed:
                            submit ? () => submitData() : null,
                            child:
                            Text('+', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),),
                          ),
                        ], // Закривається 2-ий чілдрен
                      ), //Row 1-ий
                    ),
        
                    Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 5.0,
                        ),
                        child: ListView.builder(
        
                            itemCount: todoList.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                              final item  =  todoList[index];
                              return Dismissible(
                                direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                                background: const Card(color: Colors.red,
                                child: Icon(Icons.delete_sweep,size: 30, color: Colors.white,)
                                ),
                                key: Key(todoList[index]),
                                onDismissed: (direction){
                                  setState(() {
                                    todoList.removeAt(index);
                                  });
                                },
                                child: Card(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 8.5,
                                    left: 25.0,
                                    right: 25.0,
                                  ),
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)),
                                  elevation: 0.0,
                                  child:
                                  ListTile(
                                    title: Text(todoList[index],
                                    ),),
                                ),
        
                              );
                            },
                        ),
                      )
        
                    ),
        
                  ],
                ),
           );
          }
        }
```

Tried different options for removal. Watched videos and read articles. None of the considered options work.Maybe I have a bug in the code.

Comment: Can you include full widget with sample data?

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh Yes, of course

Comment: If you are restarting it and have a list todoList hardcoded it will reload that list.

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh It's not an error, it just doesn't delete the entry

Comment: try to setStringList after removing item, I've included a post on answer section, try it

Answer (score 0):

Update the list while removing item on `SharedPreferences`

```dart
onDismissed: (direction) async {
  setState(() {
    todoList.removeAt(index);
  });
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setStringList('todo_list', todoList);
},
```

Comment: Does not work((

Comment: Item didn't get deleted after removing it ?  btw try to build the app and check without debug mode.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be deleted, but after a Hot Restart it appears again, okey, I'll try now

Comment: Does not work(((

Comment: hot restart will rebuild the app, means building from 1st step. install the app on device, then  unplug the device(just making sure you aren't doing hot restart)

Comment: does not work. I think that there is an error in the code